# WebLogic Error: Parsing failure in config.xml; The provider Provider already exists

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

When starting WebLogic server v12c, I am receiving the following error:

```
<Dec 2, 2020 8:17:27 AM CST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 5 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl$ParseException: [Management:141266]Parsing failure in config.xml: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provider Provider already exists.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessImpl
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessService
4. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.t3.srvr.FinalThreadLocalService errors were found
5. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.t3.srvr.FinalThreadLocalService
```

The WebLogic server is being started via MyEclipse. I've added the server via Window -> Preferences -> Servers -> Runtime Environments -> WebLogic, then adding **Oracle WebLogic Server 12c**.

My **config.xml** file is set to this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<domain xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd">
  <name>[app_name]</name>
  <domain-version>12.1.1.0</domain-version>
  <security-configuration>
    <name>[app_name]</name>
    <realm>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-authenticatorType"></sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-identity-asserterType">
        <sec:active-type>AuthenticatedUser</sec:active-type>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:role-mapper xmlns:xac="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml" xsi:type="xac:xacml-role-mapperType"></sec:role-mapper>
      <sec:authorizer xmlns:xac="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml" xsi:type="xac:xacml-authorizerType"></sec:authorizer>
      <sec:adjudicator xsi:type="wls:default-adjudicatorType"></sec:adjudicator>
      <sec:credential-mapper xsi:type="wls:default-credential-mapperType"></sec:credential-mapper>
      <sec:cert-path-provider xsi:type="wls:web-logic-cert-path-providerType"></sec:cert-path-provider>
      <sec:cert-path-builder>WebLogicCertPathProvider</sec:cert-path-builder>
      <sec:name>myrealm</sec:name>
    </realm>
    <default-realm>myrealm</default-realm>
    <credential-encrypted>[encrypted_password]</credential-encrypted>
    <node-manager-username>[username]</node-manager-username>
    <node-manager-password-encrypted>[encrypted_password]</node-manager-password-encrypted>
  </security-configuration>
  <server>
    <name>AdminServer</name>
    <listen-address>7001</listen-address>
    <server-start>
      <class-path>C:/[invalid_path];</class-path>
      <password-encrypted>[encrypted_password]</password-encrypted>
    </server-start>
  </server>
  <embedded-ldap>
    <name>[app_name]</name>
    <credential-encrypted>[encrypted_password]</credential-encrypted>
  </embedded-ldap>
  <configuration-version>12.1.1.0</configuration-version>
  <app-deployment>
    <name>[app_name_dir]</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>autodeploy\[app_name]</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
    <staging-mode>nostage</staging-mode>
  </app-deployment>
  <web-app-container>
    <x-powered-by-header-level>SHORT</x-powered-by-header-level>
    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
  </web-app-container>
  <jms-system-resource>
    <name>[app_name] Module</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jms/[app_name]_lockbox_module-4304-jms.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jms-system-resource>
  <admin-server-name>AdminServer</admin-server-name>
  <jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>[app_name_ds]</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/[app_name_ds]-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jdbc-system-resource>
  <jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>[app_name_mds]</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/[app_name_mds]-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jdbc-system-resource>
</domain>
```

The  for  is actually not a valid directory, but I'm not sure what should be assigned to it.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what version of MyEclipse you are using, and, whether the server starts up find outside of MyEclipse? Also, would recommend creating a post on our forums (https://myeclipseide.com/forums) or writing to us at support@genuitec.com for a more streamlined support experience. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Brian Fernandes. I was able to resolve this luckily.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by setting my **DMW_HOME** VM argument to my Middleware home directory.

For example:

```
-DMV_HOME="<your middleware home directory>"
```

In MyEclipse, this was in the **Lauch Configuration** of the WebLogic server runtime environment.

I attempted to set **MW_HOME** environment variable, but this did not work.